# Why is my Alder Lake CPUID reporting it is not Hardware P-States capable?

Tags: x86, x86-64, intel, cpuid

I have an Intel i5-1235U. The CPUID reports that it is not Hardware P-States (HWP) capable. According to Intel, all of the Alder Lake CPUs support HWP. The CPUID is reporting no HWP on both Windows and Linux. Here is the relevant output of `cpuid` in Linux (kernel 6.1):

```
 Thermal and Power Management Features (6):
      digital thermometer                     = true
      Intel Turbo Boost Technology            = true
      ARAT always running APIC timer          = true
      PLN power limit notification            = true
      ECMD extended clock modulation duty     = true
      PTM package thermal management          = true
      HWP base registers                      = false
      HWP notification                        = false
      HWP activity window                     = false
      HWP energy performance preference       = false
      HWP package level request               = false
      HDC base registers                      = false
      Intel Turbo Boost Max Technology 3.0    = false
      HWP capabilities                        = false
      HWP PECI override                       = false
      flexible HWP                            = false
      IA32_HWP_REQUEST MSR fast access mode   = false
      HW_FEEDBACK MSRs supported              = true
      ignoring idle logical processor HWP req = false
```

And here is the `cpuid` CPU info:

```
CPU 0:
   vendor_id = "GenuineIntel"
   version information (1/eax):
      processor type  = primary processor (0)
      family          = 0x6 (6)
      model           = 0xa (10)
      stepping id     = 0x4 (4)
      extended family = 0x0 (0)
      extended model  = 0x9 (9)
      (family synth)  = 0x6 (6)
      (model synth)   = 0x9a (154)
      (simple synth)  = Intel Atom (Alder Lake-P) [Golden Cove], 10nm
```

HWP is not disabled in the BIOS. In fact, the BIOS is not even giving me an option to enable/disable HWP because the CPUID says it is not HWP capable.